# Can I use @media in my HTML page?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I would like to use @media in my html page but I don't know if that is possible or not.

I have seen W3schools do this:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="img_smallflower.jpg" media="(max-width: 400px)">
  <source srcset="img_flowers.jpg">
  <img src="img_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

So I thought maybe I can do this:

```
<form>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="zoeken" media="(min-width: 613px)">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="*" media="(max-width: 613px)">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Artikelen..">
</form>
```

So I tried to let the 1 button show if its under 613px, the other if its above 613px. But it just shows them next to each other. Is this media thing only possible with `<picture>` and `<video>`?

---

**Update**

Answer taught me it's only possible with some tags.

I could make it work with media-queries with `display:none` for example:

```
<form>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="zoeken" class="bigger680">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="..." class="smaller680">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Artikelen..">
</form>

<style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
        .bigger680{
            display: none;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 680px) {
        .smaller680{
            display: none;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Place them in ``<style>`` tags and target the elements instead? Also, media queries never start with the value. ``@media screen and (min-width: Xpx)``.

Comment: What do you mean with "never start with the value"? I did it the same as the example of W3schools didn't I? And how can I target it in css so it shows the 1 if the screen is bigger then Xpx, and the other if it smaller than Xpx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use them in a limited way on some elements like a, area or link like documentated here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_media.asp

But I wouldn't recommend this, cause it violates the separation of concerns. HTML is designed to organize the structure of a page, where CSS is responsible for the presentation of those elements. You should use CSS classes/ids to apply our CSS.

It also gives you more flexibility, since its possible to apply media queries to every element without limitation. Using the inline approach, you propably will have some queries in the html document and others in our stylesheet.

Comment: My teacher told me it's bad to have any inline-style. So can't I better do that in my external css file?  Also I don't know how to change the placeholder in css cause that's something written in the html page.
 Oh and ty for that w3 list :)

Comment: I found out how to do it in css ty :)

Comment: @Minegolfer Yes, that's a good recommendation. I would use Inline-Style only when its dynamically generated and small. Like setting the color of a counter to red when it's value is larger than 0 or something like that. But especially when it become too complex, its good practice to use a individual CSS class, which can be formatted in the stylesheet.